# Problems with a GUI signal processing toolbox

Tags: matlab, user-interface, signal-processing

I'm trying to use a gui time-frequency toolbox in Matlab, but i can't find the proper function for one specific option and everytime I have to run it manually (using the gui form for calling the option)

The toolbox name is TFSA 6.3 from:

http://time-frequency.net/tf/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=38&Itemid=48

I am trying to use the LS polynomial coefficients algorithm in IF estimation tool. I know you may say that I need to read the user manual and find the right function in order to call it in the middle of program. trust me, I did it and there was nothing about this particular option.
I need to know if there is a way for using this gui toolbox without using the graphical interface, for example saving the history of my clicks...
One more thing! All the toolbox files are protected and I can't open them.

Comment: I doubt youll find an answer. If it is a closed toolbox where there is something that is not in the docs... Why dont you email the authors?

Comment: Already emailed them, no answer... :(

Comment: Unfortunately there is no  much we can do about that!